# javascript with many html pages

Tags: javascript, html

actually I have a javascript and I need to use it by multiple html pages, but I need to keep modifications on variables, so if one html page changed some variable value the other html pages can see the change, something like static variables, can anyone help?

Comment: Or, you could use a (small) frame to contain your 'static' vars - although perhaps inadvisable if in the public domain.

Answer (score 2):

Three ways:

- [Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
- [Using GET with url variables](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/variables2.php)
- [Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

Since it appears you are new to web development now might be the time to learn about these, I've provided links for reference, but they are easily searchable.